# Why is WPF so unsafe that it must flag its Windows as 'unmanaged'?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, security, permissions

I'm re-writing the front end to my service and for my installer to update the registry it will require (for Vista and 7 HP users) a request to authenticate (like Administrator privilege).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx states that WPF's Window requires "UnmanagedCode security permission". What are the implications, in terms of security prompts, of changing the front end from Win Forms to WPF? Is it really that much more flexible than Forms that it has to break all the safety guarantees I have only just embraced with .NET and managed Forms?

Comment: Are you asking a question or are you ranting? I can't tell.

Comment: Question, will this affect my users experience, re: prompts to grant permission to install (&uninstall)? It is funny how all the properties in my Forms builder have vanished though, I guess it's all hard coded now?

Comment: How would we know? You haven't shown anything about your code.

Comment: I would have upvoted this question, except for the rant.

Comment: @John Saunders, sorry, what rant do you mean? My comment? Just another question, interpret it how you like.

Comment: John, I did interpret it as I liked. Your attitude and assumptions detract from a good question.

Comment: If I didn't fall to assuming I would have no questions to clarify. It's easy to take things the wrong way when there is scarce information provided or required. I should have created a separate question with that comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3311/discussion-between-john-silver-and-john-saunders)

Comment: When I said interpret it as you like, it was an analogy for, "people believe what they want to believe". If this was all the bad attitude I displayed, then please accept my apologies for begging your criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only an issue when running in restricted trust (in-browser applications such a ClickOnce or XBAPs).
Such applications cannot freely create popup windows; this prevents phishing attacks.

As MSDN clearly states, this is not an issue for applications executed from the local machine.
It has nothing to do with administrative privileges.

Comment: But unmanaged code will present its associated problems, as in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165448/unmanaged-leak-in-a-trivial-wpf-application, right, or is that rather the exception than the norm?

Comment: **All** .Net UI technologies use unmanaged code.  WPF actually uses less of it than WinForms.  That is an already-fixed bug.

Answer (score 3):

Keep reading the linked docs:

> Window requires UnmanagedCode security permission to be instantiated.
>   **For applications installed on and launched from the local machine,
>   this falls within the set of permissions that are granted to the
>   application.**
>
> However, this falls outside the set of permissions granted to
>   applications that are launched from the Internet or Local intranet
>   zone using ClickOnce. Consequently, users will receive a ClickOnce
>   security warning and will need to elevate the permission set for the
>   application to full trust.

As long as the app is launched as a local application, there shouldn't be any prompts.

Comment: Granted, I've just had so many account issues writing my first service last week that I wondered if I'd be better sticking to Forms until MS has made WPF 'safer'. Just moved from mixed mode C++/CLI, seemed like I was about to regress. I think I read that "For applications installed ... from the local machine" as in developed for own use only, sorry, I'm a VC#Express punter.

Comment: @John I doubt WPF will be getting "safer" any time soon. I think (though hopefully someone will correct me if I'm wrong) that the reason for the security requirement is that the WPF rendering engine uses DirectX, which entails calling into a number of unmanaged libraries.

Comment: As in this fella's post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165448/unmanaged-leak-in-a-trivial-wpf-application, aren't we going full circle leaving open such possiblities? Especially now the data structures that leak have been abstracted into higher level classes. Sorry if this is starting to sound like a discussion.